# MacRuby NSBeginAlertSheet call gives unknown: [BUG] unknown Objective-C immediate: 0x1 (nil)

Tags: macruby

As a MacRuby beginner I am working through this [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/UsingMacRuby/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010259), and want to add a drop-down sheet to warn when the user tries to delete an entry from the app.

Following the code [here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/10/05/cocoa.html?page=2), which in Obj-C is

```
- (IBAction)deleteRecord:(id)sender 
{
  NSString *title = @"Warning!";
  NSString *defaultButton = @"Delete";
  NSString *alternateButton = @"Don't Delete";
  NSString *otherButton = nil;
  NSString *message = @"Are you sure you want to delete the selected record(s)?";

  if ( [tableView numberOfSelectedRows] == 0 )
    return;

  NSBeep();
  NSBeginAlertSheet(title, defaultButton, alternateButton, otherButton, mainWindow, self, @selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:), nil, nil, message);
}
```

I have in MacRuby:

```
def removeFriend(sender)
  return if @friendsTableView.numberOfSelectedRows == 0
  title = 'Warning!'
  defaultButton = 'Delete'
  alternateButton = 'Don\'t Delete'
  otherButton = nil
  s = @friendsTableView.numberOfSelectedRows > 1 ? 's' : ''
  message = "Are you sure you want to delete the selected record#{s}?"
  NSBeginAlertSheet(title, defaultButton, alternateButton, otherButton, @mainWindow, self, :'alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:', nil, nil, message)
end
```

and for `alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo`:

```
def alertDidEnd(sheet, returnCode:rCode, contextInfo:cInfo)
  <array handling code>
end
```

When this runs I get a drop-down sheet when the button linked to `removeFriend` is clicked, but then if I click "Delete" my app crashes with the following error:

```
unknown: [BUG] unknown Objective-C immediate: 0x1 (nil)

MacRuby 0.12 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]

(lldb)
```

Am I doing something wrong with the way the `didAlertEnd` method is implemented, or is this actually a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a MacRuby bug: http://www.macruby.org/trac/ticket/1368